# Is there a way to customize the buttons on an input dialog box?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create an input dialog box where I have customized buttons. I was trying to create a `showOptionDialog` with the customized buttons, but then I was unable to place the text area where it would be in an input dialog box. How would I do this?

Here's the code I used:

```
Object[] buttons = { "Submit", "Cancel" };
jtxf = new JTextField(15);
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Enter a Student ID", "Student ID",
                             JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                             JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, buttons,
                             buttons[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#button) out.  You can read the full page but the link goes directly to the customize buttons section.

Or you can use the showInputDialog as below:

```
String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            this,
            "Complete the sentence:\n"
                    + "\"Green eggs and...\"",
            "Customized Dialog",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null,
            null,
            "enter text here");
```

Comment: Yeah, I've read that tutorial, but it still didn't help me with my specific issue which was a dialog box that had a text area for user input along with customized buttons. The tutorial only showed one or the other

Comment: You may need to create your own JDialog rather than using the 'canned' showOptionPane if you can't get it positioned correctly.

Comment: I editted the answer to include another option - showInputDialog.

Comment: Keep in mind that answers heavily dependent on a link [is not particularly appropriate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259); it's better to include the essential parts of the answer here, and just provide the link for additional reference. I realize that you're providing two solutions here, one being heavily dependent on a link - as such, it would be preferable to elaborate on that solution in the answer itself in sufficient detail so clicking on the link isn't required.

Comment: Point taken.  I just started contributing more to SO in the last month or so and didn't/haven't learned all the correct etiquette around answers, comments, edits, etc.